# Unexpected behavior adobe edge animate html with YouTube embed player (youtube-iframe-api)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, adobe-edge, youtube-iframe-api

I'm getting unexpected behavior on my Edobe Edge Animate html when using YouTube embeded videos.

The problem is happening when i click the YouTube Play Button (>) on an embeded YouTube video.

When i hit the button, all Stage Elements jumps to the left.

This is the code i'm using to load youtube video on edge animate Stage (compositionReady):

```html
var youtubevid = $("<iframe/>");
sym.$("vcontainer").append(youtubevid);

youtubevid.attr('type','text/html');
youtubevid.attr('width','560');
youtubevid.attr('height','315');
youtubevid.attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID');
youtubevid.attr('frameborder','0');
youtubevid.attr('allowfullscreen','0');
```

Anyone facing the same problem? Is there any fix?

Comment: As of now, your question doesn't really suit StackOverflow format. Is this problem related to your code ? If so, could you show the relevant part of your code ? What specific steps have you tried to correct this issue ?

Comment: i've updated the post.